# Sidebars on different ViewControllers using same SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

I have used `SWRevealViewController` to create side bar. As in this I have used my `HomeViewController` as **front** and `SidebarViewController` as **right**.
My `SidebarViewController` contain a `UITableView`(Having different subject names). I want to open a new `ViewController` say `QuestionsViewController` on selection of any subject.
Now my problem is I want to use `SWRevealViewController` again to have a sidebar in `QuestionViewController` but in `SWRevealViewController` identifier for front segue `sw_front` is a constant string so how can I change it or having any other way to have that sidebar in `QuestionViewController` also.

**In Short** : Can we have same sidebars in different `ViewControllers` using `SWRevelViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this, we can change front and rear `ViewControllers` by using following code.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.revealViewController setRightViewController:[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SideBarVC"]]; // To change rightViewController
[self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"] animated:YES]; // To change frontViewController
```

For this we have to use `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController` as segue class for other `FrontViewControllers`

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply connect your RevealViewController to your new view controller with "reveal view controller set controller" segue

[image: Resultant image added]

Comment: Actually I have added that but on run time I need to change its Front & Rare View controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
create NavigationViewController with HomeViewController,
segue the RevealViewController to the NavigationController as "reveal view controller set controller",
segue HomeViewController to the QuestionViewController as "show",
on both add "bar button item"(named:"OpenSideBar") on the left of the NavBar,
create an outlet to both in their swift files and add to your viewDidLoad next:

```
    OpenSideBar.target = self.revealViewController()
    OpenSideBar.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
```

**worked for me

Comment: By the way don't forget to set the RevealViewConroller as Initial view controller